# how to use .env.qa or .env.staging with create react app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, dotenv, env-cmd

The CreateReactApp documentation shows that you can use a limited number of .env files.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

I want to use more .env files for other environments, but `.env.development` is  always used.

How can I use other files? I've found this article but it is not working for me.
https://medium.com/@tacomanator/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d

I'm using `react-scripts` v3.4.1

Answer (score 14):

Well, the article is actually right. I had a bug in my code, where I had hard-coded the value rather than relying on `process.env.REACT_APP_SOMEVAR`

These scripts in package.json work fine:

```
"start": "REACT_APP_ENV=dev npm run start-env",
"start-env": "sh -ac '. .env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts start'",
"start-dev": "REACT_APP_ENV=dev npm run start-env",
"start-qa": "REACT_APP_ENV=qa npm run start-env",
"build": "REACT_APP_ENV=dev npm run build-env",
"build-env": "sh -ac '. .env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts build'",
"build-dev": "REACT_APP_ENV=dev npm run build-env",
"build-qa": "REACT_APP_ENV=qa npm run build-env",
```

Answer (score 3):

`create-react-app` officially addresses this desire [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#customizing-environment-variables-for-arbitrary-build-environments).

They advise creating your custom `.env` then loading it using npm package [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) in a custom build script.

So, from their documentation:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging npm run build"
  }
}
```

Comment: Only this suggestion works for me